# Is JWT secure for passing confidential data

Tags: c#, encryption, oauth-2.0, jwt

I am just reading about JWT to encrypt some personal data of the user so that it can be passed to other APIs securely.

```
     var payload = new Dictionary<string, object>()
                                  {
                                      {"email", "test@test.com"},
                                      {"phone", "9878987899"}
                                  };
    var encoded = JWT.JsonWebToken.Encode(payload, "secret", JwtHashAlgorithm.HS512);
    Console.WriteLine(encoded);  //prints encoded payload
```

Now i can decode the token as shown below

```
  var decoded = JWT.JsonWebToken.Decode(encoded, "", verify:false);   // no security key
  Console.WriteLine(decoded);
```

The above code decodes the token and returns json payload which is encrypted. If you observe i didn't pass `secret key` but still i can decode the token.

I passed `verify:false` above. Now if i set it to `true` then it fails saying `Signature is Invalid`. This is the expected behaviour.

My question is ,  What is the purpose of `security key` if anyone can decode the token by setting `verify:false` ?

Comment: The key is there so you can check if someone else has changed the message.

Comment: @jao thanks. So anyone can decode the token using `JWT debugger` or some other tool. But they can't tamper it unless they have `security key`.  Is it safe to store confidential info in JWT ?

Comment: I wouldn't store a password or a customer's address in a JWT. Also, see https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/09/28/attacking-jwt-authentication/ and https://stormpath.com/blog/jwt-the-right-way